# Insanely weird django-mongoengine error

Tags: django, mongoengine

This is the most weird and illogical error I have ever seen. I am using django+mongoengine, and lets say my view is:

```
def index(request, template_name='index.html'):

    articles = Article.objects.order_by('-date_added')

    for i in articles: # test to see if the ordering works
        print i.title # ok, prints correctly all the titles ordered_by "-date_added"

    return render_to_response( template_name, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But when I loop through articles in index.html, those are always presented as if the ordering was order_by('date_added')

Am I drunk? Am I missing something? Any suggestions? This is gonna drive me crazy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: This was actually an issue with mongoengine's version. Just install from the dev branch of mongoengine...

Comment: The one that is available even now..Here is where I actually found the solution https://github.com/hmarr/mongoengine/issues/190